# A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.StringLocalizer could not be located

Tags: azure, blazor, webassembly

My Blazor WebAssembly published to Azure Static Files gives the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.StringLocalizer`1[CommandesAEmporter.Pages.Index]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.StringLocalizer`1[CommandesAEmporter.Pages.Index]' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
```

When run on my PC, it works fine. I am using the following in my project:

```
-Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"--

  --PropertyGroup--
    --TargetFramework--netstandard2.1--/TargetFramework--
    --RazorLangVersion--3.0--/RazorLangVersion--
    --ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest--service-worker-assets.js--/ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest--
  --/PropertyGroup--

  --ItemGroup--
    --PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.4.2" /--
    --PackageReference Include="Blazored.LocalStorage" Version="2.1.6" /--
    --PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="3.2.0" /--
    --PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Build" Version="3.2.0" PrivateAssets="all" /--
    --PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="3.2.0" PrivateAssets="all" /--
    --PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="3.1.4" /--
    --PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization" Version="3.1.5" /--
    --PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="3.2.0" /--
  --/ItemGroup--

  --ItemGroup--
    --ServiceWorker Include="wwwroot\service-worker.js" PublishedContent="wwwroot\service-worker.published.js" /--
  --/ItemGroup--
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**`I hope this helps you`**

when you build your solution with release mode cannot create a default language English a DLL file when the resource file name is **Resource.resx**  but if your file name **Resource.en.resx** then generate the DLL file and I am also sharing screenshots which you have to rename files.

**`also, change in a startup.cs`**

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Define the list of cultures your app will support
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("de")
            };
            // Set the default culture
            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

[Resource.resx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3jFf.png)

[Resource.en.resx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0owh.png)